# pjax click event double fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, pjax

how can i fix this problem with pjax, when i have toggle event to fadein and fadeout, and when i click on that element it fadein then fadeout, on one click ?

pjax call:

```
$.pjax.defaults.timeout = 3000;
$(document).pjax('a', '#main_wrapper');
```

click event:

```
$('body').on('click', '.element_class', function() {
    ...
});
```

Check here: [link](http://eventill.com/)
Click on "Calendar" link at top header(to load page with pjax), then click on "+" for filter..

This is happening with pjax and wiselinks.

Comment: Hi Mizra, 
I've just run into the double fire issue as well. You find a way to resolve this?

Comment: No, can't find solution for this. Please write it here if you find out.